# Weblogic Maven Plugin Deployment Issue

Tags: maven, weblogic

I'm using eclipse Kepler, Weblogic 10.3.5 and Maven 3.0.5 with the Weblogic-Maven-Plugin.  When I deploy my application using eclipse Run As...Run On Server, this is what I get:

[image: Deployed thru eclipse]

When I deploy this way, you see the application on the Weblogic Server and I'm able to reach my application through my localhost link.

When I use the Weblogic-Maven-Plugin, this is what I get:

[image: Deployed thru Maven]

You see the application has been placed under the adminServer and I get an error when I try to reach the application through my localhost link (Yes, I even ran the start-app command).

I have few questions:

1. Why is it that when I use the weblogic-maven-plugin, it deploys under the adminServer?
2. Is there a way to have the weblogic-maven-plugin deploy in a similar fashion as the Run As option in eclipse?
3. Why can I not reach the application with my localhost link after deploying with the plugin?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For which type of application are you doing this?

Answer (score -1):

I face this problem some weeks ago but in another environment Jdeveloper 12c with Maven and OJMake and OJDeploy.

The deployment is the last step on your way to run our application on WLS(WebLogic Server)

How do i solve the issue?

1. I create an Maven Ear projet
2. I create also Maven War project
3. I add the war project in the ear project also dependency and later also web_module
4. My deploy(to WLS) Configuration is in the pom from Ear project.

I you use run as from Eclipse or Jdeveloper there is a complex mechanism which do the work for us. If we want maven to do the job for us, then we must tell him what to do. We must also know   what type of archive file we suppose to send/deploy to WLS

Comment: do you hava an example of telling Maven what to do?

Comment: @NuAlphaMan No. I want to know for which type application are dealing with?

Comment: Did my answer help's you?

Comment: No.  Do you have an example?

Comment: I have an example but it's with jdeveloper 12c. If you don't care you send me your project push it somewhere where i can get it